# Finding max number and location in multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: array, matlab

I am attempting to find the maximum value and its location in multidimensional array using Matlab. There are functions `findMax3`, `findMax4`, `findMax5` and `findMax6` for dealing with different dimension cases.

**The experimental implementation**

```
function [maxNum, v1, v2, v3] = findMax3(input3d)
    maxNum = max(input3d, [], 'all');
    index = find(input3d(:) == maxNum );
    %The dimensions of the array needs to be fed as an input to ind2sub function
    [v1, v2, v3] = ind2sub(size(input3d),index);
end

function [maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4] = findMax4(input4d)
    maxNum = max(input4d, [], 'all');
    index = find(input4d(:) == maxNum );
    %The dimensions of the array needs to be fed as an input to ind2sub function
    [v1, v2, v3, v4] = ind2sub(size(input4d),index);
end

function [maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5] = findMax5(input5d)
    maxNum = max(input5d, [], 'all');
    index = find(input5d(:) == maxNum );
    %The dimensions of the array needs to be fed as an input to ind2sub function
    [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5] = ind2sub(size(input5d),index);
end

function [maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6] = findMax6(input6d)
    maxNum = max(input6d, [], 'all');
    index = find(input6d(:) == maxNum );
    %The dimensions of the array needs to be fed as an input to ind2sub function
    [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6] = ind2sub(size(input6d),index);
end
```

**Test cases**

```
% Unit tests for findMax function

%%  Three-dimensional case

sizeNum = 10;
TestArray = zeros(sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum);
TestArray(1, 2, 3) = 1;
[maxNum, v1,v2,v3] = findMax3(TestArray)

%%  Four-dimensional case

sizeNum = 10;
TestArray = zeros(sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum);
TestArray(1, 2, 3, 4) = 1;
[maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4] = findMax4(TestArray)

%%  Five-dimensional case

sizeNum = 10;
TestArray = zeros(sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum);
TestArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = 1;
[maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5] = findMax5(TestArray)

%%  Six-dimensional case

sizeNum = 10;
TestArray = zeros(sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum);
TestArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) = 1;
[maxNum, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6] = findMax6(TestArray)
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider what would happen if there are more than one element in the array with the same maximum value? `max` returns one of them, but your `find` will return the index to all of them.

One solution is to use [the new syntax for `max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#d123e830690): `[M,I] = max(A,[],___,'linear')` (I don’t know when it was introduced, but I just learned about it now).

This syntax is equal to the old-fashioned `[M,I] = max(A(:))`, which will work even in 20-year-old versions of MATLAB. Note that `A(:)` creates a vector, but doesn’t copy data, it is an essentially free operation.

The `I` output is the linear index, just as returned by `find`, except it’s always a single value. This is also faster because there is no need to create the intermediate array `input3d(:) == maxNum`.

The next thing I would do is find a way to combine all these functions into a single one that works for any number of dimensions. This requires solving the conundrum of calling `ind2sub` with the right number of output arguments. There’s a trick for that:

```matlab
coords = cell(1, ndims(A));
[coords{:}] = ind2sub(size(A), I);
```

You could then put the coordinates into a regular array: `coords = [coords{:}]`, to make the function easier to use.

In your unit tests, use `assert` to verify that the outputs have the expected values:

```matlab
sizeNum = 10;
TestArray = zeros(sizeNum, sizeNum, sizeNum);
TestArray(1, 2, 3) = 1;
[maxNum, v1,v2,v3] = findMax3(TestArray);
assert(maxNum = 1)
assert(v1 == 1);
assert(v2 == 2);
assert(v3 == 3);
```